# Find least frequent value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on a problem that asks me to return the least frequent value in a dictionary and I can't seem to work it out besides with a few different counts, but there aren't a set number of values in the dictionaries being provided in the checks.

> For example, suppose the dictionary contains mappings from students' names (strings) to their ages (integers). Your method would return the least frequently occurring age. Consider a dictionary variable d containing the following key/value pairs:
>
> {'Alyssa':22, 'Char':25, 'Dan':25, 'Jeff':20, 'Kasey':20, 'Kim':20, 'Mogran':25, 'Ryan':25, 'Stef':22}
>
> Three people are age 20 (Jeff, Kasey, and Kim), two people are age 22 (Alyssa and Stef), and four people are age 25 (Char, Dan, Mogran, and Ryan). So rarest(d) returns 22 because only two people are that age.

Would anyone mind pointing me in the right direction please? Thanks!

Comment: What would you return in the case of a tie?

Comment: That's actually a good question...how would you deal with a tie of the two least common?

Comment: Depends on what the requirements say. Maybe you should return a list of all the least common (in which case, you should return a one element long list when there _isn't_ a tie), or maybe you should raise an Exception, or maybe you should choose one of the least common ones and return that. Or maybe the client somehow knows there never will be a tie, so they don't care what you do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Counting the members of a collection is the job of `collections.Counter`:

```
d={'Alyssa':22, 'Char':25, 'Dan':25, 'Jeff':20, 'Kasey':20, 'Kim':20, 'Mogran':25, 'Ryan':25, 'Stef':22}
import collections
print collections.Counter(d.values()).most_common()[-1][0]
22
```

Comment: Worked great! I appreciate all your quick responses

Comment: Please remember to *vote* for all the answers that help, and *accept* the answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty dict for the counters, then loop through the dict you've got and add 1 to the corresponding value in the second dict, then return the key of the element with the minimum value in the second dict.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
min(Counter(my_dict_of_ages.values()).items(),key=lambda x:x[1])
```

would do it i think

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter`

```
d={'Alyssa':22, 'Char':25, 'Dan':25, 'Jeff':20, 'Kasey':20, 'Kim':20, 'Mogran':25, 'Ryan':25, 'Stef':22}
import collections
print collections.Counter(d.values()).most_common()[-1][0]
```

Or write your own function:

```
def rarest(dict):
    values = dict.values()
    least_frequent = max(values)
    for x in set(values):
        if values.count(x) < least_frequent:
            least_frequent = x
    return {least_frequent:dict[least_frequent]}

>>> rarest({'Alyssa':22, 'Char':25, 'Dan':25, 'Jeff':20, 'Kasey':20, 'Kim':20, 'Mogran':25, 'Ryan':25, 'Stef':22})
{22:2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second dictionary that uses the values in the first (ages) as keys in the second, with the values of the second as counts. Then sort the values of the second and do a reverse loop-up to get the associated keys (there are a few ways to do this efficiently by treating the the list of keys and the list of values as numpy arrays).

```
import numpy

d = {'Alyssa':22, 'Char':25, 'Dan':25, 'Jeff':20, 'Kasey':20, 'Kim':20, 'Mogran':25, 'Ryan':25, 'Stef':22}

def rarest(d):
    s = {}

    # First, map ages to counts.
    for key in d:
        if d[key] not in s:
            s[d[key]] = 1
        else:
            s[d[key]] += 1 # Could use a defaultdict for this.

    # Second, sort on the counts to find the rarest.
    keys = numpy.array(s.keys())
    values = numpy.array(s.values())
    ordering = np.argsort(values)
    return keys[ordering][0]
```

There's probably a [more efficient way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19984587/13604), but that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = {'Alyssa':22, 'Char':25, 'Dan':25, 'Jeff':20, 'Kasey':20, 'Kim':20, 'Mogran':25, 'Ryan':25, 'Stef':22}
values = my_dict.values()
most_frequent = 0
for x in set(values):
    if values.count(x) > most_frequent:
        most_frequent = x
print most_frequent
```

This code uses the `set()` method, which returns a set with all unique elements, i.e.:

```
>> set([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1])
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

To extract all the values from the dict, you can use `dict.values()`. Likewise, you have `dict.keys()` and `dict.items()`.

```
>> my_dict.keys()
['Char', 'Stef', 'Kim', 'Jeff', 'Kasey', 'Dan', 'Mogran', 'Alyssa', 'Ryan']

>> my_dict.values()
[25, 22, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 22, 25]

>> my_dict.items()
[('Char', 25),
 ('Stef', 22),
 ('Kim', 20),
 ('Jeff', 20),
 ('Kasey', 20),
 ('Dan', 25),
 ('Mogran', 25),
 ('Alyssa', 22),
 ('Ryan', 25)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else prefers to remember as few function/property names and packages as possible, JadedTuna's answer is good. Here's my go-to:

```
val_count = {}
for k in d:
    if k in val_count.keys():
        val_count[k] += 1
    else:
        val_count[k] = 1
val_count = list(val_count.items())       # Convert dict to [(k1, v1), (k2, v2), ...]
val_count.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])    # Sorts by count. Add reverse=True if you'd like mode instead
val_count[0]
```